# Strange behavior with checkbox in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox

I refactored my code, moving from an Activity (containing checkboxes) to Fragment. It used to work as demanded (two-state checkbox) in the Activity but now for some reason the checkbox is a tri-state checkbox.

Fragment:

```
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="kob.outdoor.ontheflyclient.activities.settings.SettingsFragment">
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/lytSettingsTop"
        >
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkSettingsMonday"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Monday"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
            ...
```

This doesn't work (tri-state):

```
chkMonday.setChecked(settings.getBoolean(getString(R.string.chkSettingsMondayKey), true));
```

The checkbox has a tri-state and I can't figure out why:

- default state when Fragment is loaded: empty with highlighted borders.
- one click: unchecked (gray)
- one click: checked (check mark + highlighted border)

Discovered that this works (two-state):

```
boolean monday = settings.getBoolean(getString(R.string.chkSettingsMondayKey), true);
chkMonday.setChecked(monday);
```

Do you have any explanation?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe set an initial value for "checked"?

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem :(